# How to execute bash script using php using Ec2 server

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

i have created a bash script file named as shellscript.sh.Which copy content of one file add into host file.This is working when i run this manually using command

```
sh shellscript.sh
```

I want to exicute this script from php function.anytone know how to execute.Owner of this file is `ubuntu:ubuntu`.

I am using dedicated server Amazon ec2 .So have root access.php owned bu another user and file owner is ubuntu.

Comment: There are several PHP functions for executing commands: `shell_exec`, `exec`, and `system`.

Comment: i have tried shell_exec but it not executed file.

Comment: Try using the full pathname of the script.

Comment: Unless you are running your own web server, it is possible that shell execution has been disabled by your hosting provider.

Comment: ohh,@ fortune thanks for point me there.your suggested answer worked with some file permission changes.Thanks

Comment: @CyberAbhay you are welcome